How to color a table column with a specific class in its header using CSS?


table, th, td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th.red {
  background-color: red;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>q</th><th class="red">w</th><th>e</th><th>r</th><th>t</th><th>y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>q1</td><td>w1</td><td>e1</td><td>r1</td><td>t1</td><td>y1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q2</td><td>w2</td><td>e2</td><td>r2</td><td>t2</td><td>y2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Is there a way to color a table column whose header has a certain class using CSS?
For example, in this table, to color the second column.

You can also set a <colgroup>...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col


table, th, td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.col_red {
  background-color: red;
}
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col />
    <col class="col_red" />
   </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>q</th><th>w</th><th>e</th><th>r</th><th>t</th><th>y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>q1</td><td>w1</td><td>e1</td><td>r1</td><td>t1</td><td>y1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q2</td><td>w2</td><td>e2</td><td>r2</td><td>t2</td><td>y2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Wow, that's very good, thanks! One question - what to do if the column cells are already colored with their "style" attributes?

@Zourab what do you want to happen if a column cell already has a background colour?

@Zourab I don't think you will get it to work using col in that situation then. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col#usage_notes: "As the column background color is painted on top of the table and column groups (), but behind background colors applied to the row groups (, , and ), the rows (), and the individual cells ( and ), backgrounds applied to table columns are only visible if every layer painted on top of them has a transparent background."

@Brett Donald if a column cell (<td>) already has a background colour and I add the col_red class to the corresponding <col> tag then all the columns cells must be colored according to the col_red class rools

@Zourab The colgroup tag predates css3, for this kind of thing plan to use :nth-child() selector instead, with a minimum of JS code.
PS: my answer is in agreement with your question. You should ask a new question if your problem is different.

You can simulate this by using an overflowing coloration that comes from the header


table,th,td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th.red {
  position: relative;
}
th.red:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; /* a negative z-index */
  inset: 0 0 -999px; /* big value for the bottom */
  background: red;
}
table {
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the overflow of the pseudo element */
  isolation: isolate; /* make sure the coloration stay within the table (create a stacking context) */
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>q</th><th class="red">w</th><th>e</th><th>r</th><th>t</th><th>y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>q1</td><td>w1</td><td>e1</td><td>r1</td><td>t1</td><td>y1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q2</td><td>w2</td><td>e2</td><td>r2</td><td>t2</td><td>y2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




You can use an :nth-child() selector.


table, th, td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr > :nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>q</th><th>w</th><th>e</th><th>r</th><th>t</th><th>y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>q1</td><td>w1</td><td>e1</td><td>r1</td><td>t1</td><td>y1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q2</td><td>w2</td><td>e2</td><td>r2</td><td>t2</td><td>y2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




The goal is to color a column when the user clicks on its header, so we don't know the column number in advance.

also tr :nth-child(2) {
